# Bootstrap float image on the left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
     iiii   text 
     iiii   text
     iiii   text
            text
            text
```

Where

```
     iiii
     iiii
     iiii
```

is the image and on the right is the text.

If i try class `float-left`  of bootstrap i obtain this:

```
     iiii   text 
     iiii   text
     iiii   text
     text         <-- Text under the image
     text
```

Basically the remaining text goes under the image.

What is cleanest way to put the image on the left, also for the text that goes down of the image?

Comment: You can use Bootstrap's grid system and create a row with two columns.

Comment: just to put the image on the left ?

Comment: the down votes are probably because you have no code, you haven't shown us you have even tried to do it yourself, or given us any place to start.

Comment: I didnt write explicitly, but i said in the post that i have used float-left with no luck

Answer (score 0):

The correct element to use is the media object - that has a media-left and and media-body element which contains the text and an optional heading.

```css
.media-body {
padding: 16px;
} 

.media-heading {
 font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="media-object">
      <div class="media">
        <div class="media-left">
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/3c/fb/e53cfb282846313a69daf9755bfaf339.jpg" class="media-object" alt="fluffy kitten" height="150" title="Fluffy Kiten" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <div class="media-text-content">
          <h3 class="media-heading">Fluffy kitten</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively - you can swap the text and image around and use media-right for a right sided image with the heading and text on the left.

```css
.media-body {
padding: 16px;
} 

.media-heading {
 font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="media-object">
      <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
          <div class="media-text-content">
          <h3 class="media-heading">Fluffy kitten</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="media-right">
          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/3c/fb/e53cfb282846313a69daf9755bfaf339.jpg" class="media-object" alt="fluffy kitten" height="150" title="Fluffy Kiten" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just make use of a row with two columns:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    Text<br />
    Text<br />
    Text<br />
    Text<br />
    Text<br />
    Text<br />
    Text<br />
    Text<br />
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```